# Omitting JSON data from WikiMedia Rest API

Tags: flutter, mediawiki-api

I am getting data from [WikiMedia Mobile Rest Api](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/). The response is fine and data comes as JSON but there is a problem with the extracted data. There is some CSS content '.mw-parser-output' that i need to cut from the JSON.

See the attached image.[image: .mw-parser-output]
How can i omit this data from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use replaceAll on this field during deserialisation:

```
final jsonField = "Lorem .mw-parser-output ipsum";
  
print(jsonField.replaceAll('.mw-parser-output', '')); // prints Lorem  ipsum
```

Comment: I solved it. After getting the data from JSON and trying to generate html (using the html package for flutter), there is a property on every dom.Node called 'node.attributes'. This property holds information in form of key-value pairs. So there is a specific key named 'mw:Extension/templatestyles' and i just iterate through all the nodes and if that key is found then i will not add it to widget building or whatever you want to do with that. Simple as that. Note that i am using html package for flutter and generating html from string that i get from Wikimedia Mobile API.

Comment: Also, i know how to trim or replace strings but in this specific case, .mw-parser-output is a kind of css styling thing and it is generating a proper line of attributes which doesn't relates to data but to styling and should not be displayed. Apologies if i am wrong here because i don't come from a web background. Anyhow, the main solution was to remove or omit this specific generate node which i did. Hope it helps.